# Can't backup WhatsApp on Onedrive

Tags: whatsapp, onedrive, backup, nokia-lumia-530

Could not backup WhatsApp on Onedrive with a Lumia 530 phone. Any possible solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a lot of forums, there doesn't seem to be a exact solution for this problem, so I tried this,

It mostly happens due to irregular connection, Try the following to troubleshoot:

- Check properly that the Wi-Fi that you are accessing does not have any blocks set up by the firewall (as in offices and colleges) which is preventing you from accessing OneDrive.
- Make sure that the speed of the WiFi is sufficient for backing up or updating the backup.